# SQL Query for repeating numbers in results

Tags: sql, sql-query-store

1 - I usually generate a report which will have two rows for example container id and quantity where it will have container id numbers and quantity how much they created for that quantity.
problem here is for same container id, report giving different quantities because they are created in different time.
can some one please help me with a query that, for same container id it should return sum of quantities.

I've tried group by but I need SUM of the quantity to the particular container id

```
select Containers.ContainersID, Quantity
from orders
inner join ordershipmentdetail
  on orders. Okey = ordershipmentdetail.okey
inner join containerdetail
  on orders.okey = containerdetail.okey
inner join containers
  on containerdetail.containerkey = containers.containerkey
where customerid = 'D100646'
```

result example:

```
container id       quantity
ST005               1
ST005               1
ST005               1
ST005               1
RST025              2
RST025              2
RST025              2
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Please show your sample data and attempt in addition to your desired results.

Comment: [edit] and improvements directly into your question.

Comment: select Containers.ContainersID,Quantity
from orders inner join
ordershipmentdetail on orders. Okey = ordershipmentdetail.okey innerjoin
containerdetail on orders.okey = containerdetail.okey innerjoin
containers on containerdetail.containerkey = containers.containerkey
where customerid = 'D100646'

Comment: As I said [edit] any clarifications *directly* into your question.

Comment: GROUP BY the container id, and SUM the quantities.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum(Quantity)` in the columns list, and append `group by Containers.ContainersID` at the end.